# de-ignore Json fields in test cases

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I have an object where I annotated few variables with @JsonIgnore. But I wanted to check the values of those fields in test cases but I don't want it to be included in the response. For example,

```
class MyObject{

    private variable1;

    @JsonIgnore
    private variable2;

    @JsonIgnore
    private variable3;

    @JsonIgnore
    private variable4;
}
```

Here, I want to ignore variable2, variable3 and variable4 in response json when the request came from actual user(i.e from browser). But I want to include those values when I am requesting through test cases. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: @JsonIgnore accepts a parameter that sets if is activated or not. You can try to play with it to disable it for the tests: `@JsonIgnore(MODIFIER_BOOLEAN)`

Comment: How do I modify the boolean value dynamically?